# webpack's bundle.js surrounded by a function construct

Tags: webpack

Is it possible to instruct webpack, that the webpack code in bundle.js is surrounded from a function like:

```
function foo() {
// code of bundle.js}
```

So I can call the bundle code from another js file explicitly, if, for example, the browser properties are met.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. At least with webpack `^2.2.1`.

Then you basically write:

```
module.exports = (env) => {
```

instead of:

```
module.exports = {
```

First parameter that your config function get is `process.env` variable.